# Voronoi polygons along given border in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, voronoi-thiessen, borders

I have a shapefile that contains districts (polygons) of a country. I added centroids to each district in order to create Voronoi poylgons around them. On this new layer, the outlines of the Voronoi polygones divide some of the districts into two when merging the layers. For example:

first half of district 1 belongs to Voronoi polygon 1
second half of district 1 belongs to Voronoi polygon 2

However, I would like to merge both layers in which each district belongs to one Voronoi polygon only based on the highest procentual overlap. For example:

district 1 belongs to Voronoi polygon 1 because it has a 70% overlap with Voronoi polygon 1 and only 30% with Voronoi polygone 2.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Plugins` -> `Manage and Install plugins` -> search for `mmqgis` -> install. Then go to MMQGIS in the tab bar, it might be between `Processing` and `help`, click on it, go to `Combine` -> `Spatial Join`. Here you can put in your layers and change the `Field operation` to `Largest proportion`

Comment: Please mark as answered if it has solved your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you a lot!